# Base64 special characters new File

Tags: android, base64, filenames

I'm working in Android, developping an app in which I'm uploading files to dropbox. As i don't want the title of this files to be seen, i'm encrypting them and the enccoding the result bytearray. The problem is that when you use the sentences:

```
String fileNameEncrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
File file = new File(mDirectoryPath + "/" + fileNameEncrypted);
```

The string "fileNameEncrypted" contains forward and back slashes and maybe other characters that are not allowed for a file name. Besides, the forward slashes are confused with subfolders.

How could I solve this problem?

PS: my goal is the filename can't be read in the dropbox app.

Comment: No no, I'm encrypting the file name and then encoding it to get a new file name which is the one i want to use for the file i'm uploading to dropbox. Sorry, i was in a hurry and looking again at my question i didn't make myself clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT the whole message according to comments]

Because base64 encode use special char (/) and lower/upper case char, it's seems to not be very compliant with filename for some OS like windows. Where file "aaa.txt" is equals to "AAA.txt".

Even the safe mode of base64 use lower and upper case charset.

The ASCII hex format (base16) provides a more compliant charset 0-9 A-F for store byte array

> the char 'A' = 0x41 in base16. You can wrote this as "41"

A more complete example

> "test.txt" can be translate to : 746573742E747874

If you need to really hide the name you can combine the encoding with a hash function.  Because hash is a one way function you will definitely hide the filename, but you will not be capable to recover the real name from this.

If you need a two way function you can use a simple crypto method like aes with a internal key

You can use the Guava library to perform the transformation on base16 or base32 who has a more compliant charset than base64 for windows.

```
byte[] encrypted = "test.txt".getBytes();
BaseEncoding encoder = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase();
String newFilename = encoder.encode(encrypted);
```

If you want to use base32 juste change the encoder.

Comment: Yes, good point. You're essentially repeating what is contained in the question that I linked that is duplicated. It is not ok to answer questions that are duplicate. Though, you can try another angle, for example with Base32 encoding or even HEX.

Comment: Sorry, I am low experience user with SO response, and I was do some errors with my previous comment and delete it.

I have not see your duplicate comment before I post my first answer.

Secont point I have deleted my previous comment where I point that you have right with the '=' but because base64 use upper and lower (a-A) char and windows dones't differenciate them that's can lead to problem. I will be more prudent for my next answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the base64 encoder in filename safe mode with

```
Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.URL_SAFE)
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#URL_SAFE):

> Encoder/decoder flag bit to indicate using the "URL and filename safe" variant of Base64 (see RFC 3548 section 4) where - and _ are used in place of + and /.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Notice the `android` tag - the duplicate is just java. Working with `android.util.Base64` is different.